# Timestamp as unique ID

Tags: android, timestamp, unique

Is there something wrong if i use

```
Long uniqueId = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;

String documentName = ""+ uniqueId;
```

as for example a document name?
Unless the user has a wrong Date it will be always unique right?
Or is there a better way to create always unique number values?
The reason i use `Long uniqueId = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;`

is because it has to be unique even if the user generates that document from another device without the same data which means that i cannot create and save unique values and simply add +1 to it.

Comment: I would not use the /1000 as well

Comment: You can use https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/UUID.html

Comment: You can use [AtomicInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) along with the timetamp to get exactly unique values

Comment: Something like Daylight saving Time could kill you. Two requests at the same time. Might work well enough might not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use

`System.currentTimeMillis()/1000`

then if you save 2 files in the same second you will have 2 identical names for 2 different files.

So i suggest you to use

```
UUID.randomUUID().toString()
```

Comment: I have always been using timestamps at milliseconds level , this can have the advantage of giving a unique identifier AND time of creation of that object if you plan to store it somewhere...do not divide by anything, timestamp will be fine unless for some weird reason your app is creatings objects too fast that two consecutive objects are built in the same millisecond !

Comment: UUID is too long for a filename to have?  Is there anyway to shorten it or any other alternative?